# How can I tell my manager the task I was assigned is beyond my current ability?

Tags: project-management, time-management

I was hired a year ago as a new graduate to my company. I have been learning the job as I go along, helping out with smaller tasks (modifications to C++, C#, vb6 programs) rather than being responsible for a big project on my own. My manager knows that I am not up to speed on everything and that my programming skills are not the greatest.

Recently I was assigned a new task to create an entirely new library in C++ by the end of next month. It was assigned to me because of a lack of manpower. I am not confident at all (20-30%) that I can finish this task on time.

How should I discuss this situation with my manager?

Comment: This question is a bit specific and may be tough for people to answer. I am going to edit this question to get you better responses by making it a bit broader. If you think this won't get you an answer you can use, please feel free to [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/12460/edit) the post or roll back the changes.

Comment: Have you tried to complete this? Are you behind? have you talked with the members of your team about how to complete the task?

Comment: Is the manager fully aware of your reservations regarding this assignment?

Comment: **comments removed:** Comments are intended to help improve a post or seek clarification. Please don't answer the questions in the comments. These can't be easily voted on as the best answers, and they may inadvertently prevent other users  from providing real answers. Please see [How should I post a useful non-answer if it shouldn't be a comment?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1866/98) for more guidance.

Comment: @Ramhound Being assigned projects that are **WAY** beyond someone's expertise is stupidity.  It does not help anyone grow, and only leads to frustration and stress.  Furthermore, the company won't benefit from such projects.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Start with the attitude of "I want to give it the best try I can, what are some ideas/tips for making this successful?".  Be very conscious of that as your approach and avoid any signs of despair, hopelessness or unwillingness to try.  Everyone has *some* chance of failure, and if work is urgent, and resources are tight, some work is better than no work on a critical task.

I would set up a meeting with your manager, though, "kick off" for the work.  It's a good idea even in a normal situation, but in a serious challenge, it's even more valuable.  Things to cover:

**What are my resources for learning?**

You should already know the resources for everyday work - like helpful websites, internal coding standards, how to run the environment and any development tools, etc.  This would cover things like:

- are there guidance documents for bigger projects?  Design standards, processes for peer review, etc?
- is there someone on the team who's designed something like this before who could be a go-to guy to answer questions?  How much can you tap his time (1-2 hours/week?  4-8?)
- is there something you can use as a reference?  A previously written library that everyone likes?  Some sort of sample to give you something to imitate?

**What is absolutely most important to have this month?**

Generally, the bigger the work, the more ambiguous it will be.  Refining a project, honing in on the priorities and planning out big work to be acheiveable are the critical skills of just about any sort of a senior position.  You aren't senior yet, so you probably will need help in this area.  A really key element is to ask - no one can work by psychic interaction!  Hopefully, your management is ready to provide some guidance here... but if not, be prepared with your break down of the work and a tentative thought on priorities.  It is far easier to correct a list of priorities than to develop one from nothing.

Here's my method:

1 - Write down any discrete work that comes to mind.  It might be specific features, it might be some underlying prep work that needs to happen first, it could be parts of the design phase. Chances are good that your to-do list items are a mix of all sorts of things that can't be compared.

2 - Connect any dependancies.  Once you'll have a list, you'll find cases of "can't do X, Y or Z without step 1", "can't do A or B without X" and so on.  That'll give you a place to start.

3 - Write a first priority list.  I can guarantee that you won't have a clue on a big chunk of it.  So take a guess.  Generally, anything with a lot of dependancies needs to be high on the list, and it needs to come before anything that depends upon it.  You may also order it with an eye to verifying completeness - no point in doing something if you have no way of knowing if it was done right.

4 - Book time with the boss and discuss it.  I recommend for highly uncertain work that you push hard for a very ordered priority.  Not High/Medium/Low and a "please get all Highs done by the end of the month" but an ordered list from #1 to #n.

5 - From there, try to give feedback on your *own* cut line (items higher than X will get done, don't have time for the others).  Tell your manager what you think is reasonable and have a discussion from there.  He's got a right to reprioritize, but not to tell you that you can do more work - particularly without offering additional resources (and I don't mean money!) that change your estimates.   He *can* say - "why do you think that is hard... here's a way to make it easy" - and change YOUR opinion.

A libarary is an amphorous thing - just look at the public APIs out there - they grow and grow, with many different features.  The ideal is to pare down that first attempt to a bare minimum that will get anyone waiting on it into a state where they can be productive.  Anything that won't be used should be deferred.

**How/when does the manager want status?**

You don't want to ring the alarm on every issue - but how long should you spin your wheels before begging for help?  What kind of status should you report?  How often?  In what format (email, meeting, etc)?

**What are your factors for time vs. quality?**

Chances are good that you could do a small chunk of the work pretty well, or a bigger chunk with more flaws and errors.  As you finish prioritizing, try to get a sense of which is the bigger priority.

Usually in development, this has a lot to do with what phase you are in and who's going to have to use this thing next.  For example:

- Internal, nearby fellow developers - if the next thing is software integration testing, and the folks using your work are all nearby fellow developers, it will be pretty easy to resolve early issues with a quick yell, and an informal conversation - maybe you have to fix bugs quickly, but you can do it and return the fixes with minimal overhead and no political/reputational fall out for the company.  In this case, minimal testing in favor of additional features may be the way to go.
- Customer release - if this libary gets released to external groups or a customer, and will be billed as a solid product of your company, you are on the other extreme - one, very well tested, very well designed feature may be much better than every other capability.

Chances are, your project is a shade of grey... but do the best you can to clarify this.  No manager wants to pick an absolute, but it's an important point - you can't do both in a limited time, and erring too far to the wrong extreme will mean a big gap between what you provide and what they expected, which works well for no one.

**What do I have going for me?**

Yes, this is asking for a pat on the back.  But in a tight spot, it's good to know your strengths (and your weaknesses).  From the post, it sounds like you already know your weaknesses, so it would be good to get a sense of your strengths.  Sometimes they are hard to figure out, and you want to know any good things that you already do that you should keep up.

Comment: ~"**the bigger the work, the more ambiguous it will be**".  Absolutely true.  Managers and programmers who cannot break down a big project into manageable tasks, will fail.

Comment: Who can guide & review your work, will likely be the biggest factor in whether you can achieve this.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, your manager doesn't have a choice. You having a 20+% chance is better than nothing. You indicate the manager is aware of your skill level, but pose the question as if you have to create this on time or it is the end of the world.

Keep in touch with your manager. Try to hit short and manageable mile stones. At some point you may be able to reassess the project and possibly remove some of the requirements.

Don't be so afraid of failure that you don't stretch your skills and come up with a piece of this project that is useful.

Edit: Also, consider getting some training. A one week class may move this project further in the long run. I think this is part of the idea that your manager is aware of your limitations at this point in your career and has an opportunity to excellerate you skill level.

Comment: And if there are specific things you need from your manager, ask.

Comment: Indeed, nobody ever died by crossing a deadline. Just keep everyone in the loop when deciding where to cross it. And keep in mind that some people actually have died when sprinting too fast.

Comment: @JanDoggen What if your manager thinks he already gave you enough information?  Then every time you ask, he gets more and more frustrated.  Like ~"**you should know these things already**"...

Comment: @maxy - I guess you don't work in the medical profession.

Answer (score 1):

The first positive is that you didn't say "I'm not sure I can do it"! Either one of you doesn't have an true appraisal of your capabilities, which your question seems to rule out, or your manager has made the decision to accept the likelihood of delay, because he needs other people on projects that are competing for resources.

Your responsibility is to keep him informed with regular and accurate checkins on your progress. This will give him what he needs to make the call as to whether to pull someone off other (potentially important) work to help you, and will give him ammunition if he needs to go higher up the chain of command to push for either more people in the team or more time to complete the work. If things run late because the department's undermanned, that's not your issue - do what you can, build up your C++ skill, revisit your estimates as you practice. If things run late because nobody knew there was a problem, then that is very much your issue.

Comment: What do you mean by ~"**because nobody knew there was a problem**"?  What is a **problem** in your opinion?